# Container app authentication session lifetime

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-container-apps, easy-auth

In authentication setup for container apps the user needs to reauthenticate to the application at certain points of time, this time is not specified in the official documentation nor is it clear .

I would like to extend the session of the signed in user for as long as possible or at least find out what is the session expiry time and possible actions to reauthenticate.

---

I have found some mentions of fixed 8 hours for the cookie of tha AppService authentication (which should be similar to container app authentication). This I have disproved by accessing the app with a time difference of 16 hours - 5pm and 9am the next morning - without needing to reauthenticate.

---

When setting up container app authentication I have added two identity providers, one is a custom OIDC that relies on **AzureAD B2C**, and the other one is **Microsoft**.

My next assumption was that the identity provider's access token lifetime determines the length of the session. When I retrieve the received headers in my application there is a header **X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL** it is a base64 encoded json, which contains an **exp** (expiry) claim, this claim points to the expiry time of the access token that is issued by the identity provider:

- **Sign in with Microsoft** - the expiry is around 1 hour, and I assumed that my session would by invalidated after this time has elapsed, however even after 4 hours I am still able to access the app without reauthenticating. I've even tried signing out of my microsoft account and this did not affect the session at all - the reverse holds however if I use Microsoft as an identity provider in my application and then sign out I will be signed out of all services that require a microsoft session.
- **Sign in with custom OIDC (Azure AD B2C)** - the expiry is 7 days from moment of sign in for this identity provider and I have confirmed this in the **exp** claim. I have signed in with this identity provider at 5pm and had an expiration time of 7 days, next morning at 9am I was not required to reauthenticate however the **iat** (issued at) claim showed that it was set to this time of around 9am. Repeating this in a shorter time span did not have the same effect though.

---

What is the maximum amount of time I can configure before asking the user to reauthenticate?

Is there a way to use the access tokens from the identity provider in my application (e.g. when user's sign in with Microsoft I would like to invoke GraphApi to fetch their organization info on their behalf)?

---

**EDIT - Additional find**

When restarting the container app revision there is a series of logs of the **http-auth** container (the one that is responsible for authentication, and which passes enriched requests to the application), one of these logs is a setting named **EasyAuthConfig** which has a section ***login/cookieExpiration*** which has a value of 08:00:00 (8 hours), this is in accordance with AppService's documentation.

However it is still unclear if and how could this session could be extended? (for app service there is a /.auth/refresh endpoint, for container apps invoking this endpoint does nothing)

Comment: could you explain what type of app you are deploying ? webapp / api etc ?also framework/version ? what the issue here? there are few questions and not sure which one is relevant ?

Comment: I am using a .net 5 api that also serves my frontend. For container app authentication setup it is irrelevant what is in the background because there is a middleware component which intercepts requests and forwards them enriched with authentication info, if the session is expired this middleware sends a redirect to the default authentication provider.

Comment: The issue is that I cannot determine what is the session lifetime, how this session lifetime is associated with the authentication provider used for establishing this session, and how (if there is a way) could I manage the expiration of this session without having the user to reauthenticate

Comment: I think the token store part is the key. if disable you rely on identity provider token expiration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#token-store

Comment: This would solve my issue of retrieving the user's access tokens from the underlying identity provider (e.g. Microsoft access token so GraphAPI can be accessed)

However container apps do not contain headers which contain the user's access token from the identity provider

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/authentication#access-user-claims-in-application-code

Comment: @Thomas also on container apps there is no possibility to configure the token store unfortunately.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to do non-interactive login programmatically when ad/entra I'd is set as the auth provider.  Do u have docs related to this?

Comment: I think once you complete the initial login - with whichever authentication provider - then session management is handled by the container app authentication middleware which has issued previously a cookie which is persisted in your browser.

Only connection that you can establish between your authentication provider (ad/entra) and container app authentication, is if you set the cookieExpiration property to have the value IdentityProviderDerived, in this case the container app authentication middleware will rely on the authentication provider for the session lifetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the property cookieExpiration is modifiable via bicep: [Cookie expiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.app/containerapps/authconfigs?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#cookieexpiration)

I've also received the following suggestion on the learn.microsoft website, this script should have the same effect as the bicep deployment, however I have not verified this:

```
$containerAppName = "mycontainerapp"
$resourceGroupName = "myresourcegroup"
$cookieTTL = "60.00:00:00"
$authConfig = Get-AzContainerAppAuthConfig -AuthConfigName current -ContainerAppName $containerAppName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$params = @{AuthConfigName="current";ContainerAppName=$containerAppName;ResourceGroupName=$resourceGroupName;CookieExpirationConvention="FixedTime";CookieExpirationTimeToExpiration=$cookieTTL}
$authProps = @("ForwardProxyConvention","ForwardProxyCustomHostHeaderName","ForwardProxyCustomProtoHeaderName","GlobalValidationExcludedPath","GlobalValidationRedirectToProvider","GlobalValidationUnauthenticatedClientAction","HttpSettingRequireHttps","IdentityProvider","LoginAllowedExternalRedirectUrl","LoginPreserveUrlFragmentsForLogin","NonceExpirationInterval","NonceValidateNonce","PlatformEnabled","PlatformRuntimeVersion","RouteApiPrefix","RouteLogoutEndpoint")
$authProps|ForEach-Object -Process {if ($authConfig.$_ -ne $null) {$params.Add($_.ToString(),$authConfig.$_)}}
```

New-AzContainerAppAuthConfig @params